# My MacBook A1502 boots slows at USB CR has no interface nub after 1->0 transition

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, ssd, monterey, nvram

My system

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.7.3
BuildVersion:   21H1015
```

My MacBook: `A1502`

Customizations:

I replaced original Apple SSD with `Samsung 2TB M.2 PCIe Gen4 NVMe 980 PRO` using an `M.2 NVMe` adapter. I know there are problems with these adapters, I bought exactly the one someone else is using without any trouble.

After getting disk space I upgraded from `Catalina` to `Monterey`, I noticed boot is very slow and performance in general, but not every time. Not sure if it is because of the SSD or because of upgrade.

I found the following actions make boot normal and usage normal:

1. Boot the MacBook, very slow, at least 10 minutes.
2. Right after book, shut down. Wait 10 seconds after screen backlight stops.
3. Power on again and immediately reset PRAM (option + command + P + R). Press it exactly 8 seconds until Apple logo disappears.
4. MacBook boots again, this time boot is fast or normal. Performance also is normal.

If I don't wait after shut down, PRAM reset will take no effect. If I hold PRAM reset key compbination too long it will reboot twice and also it will take no effect.

I tried to investigate why the boot is slow, I booted once in verbose mode and found at some point it gets stuck at the following message:

```
USB CR has no interface nub after 1->0 transition
```

I think it waits for something, catches timeout and then continues. Not sure why it also affects the performance after the boot and also not sure why PRAM reset resolves it.

I am able to use this MacBook normally, it just takes long time to boot it because I need to do it once extremely slow, then again with PRAM reset and its just a bit annoying, however once done everything runs smoothly with new SSD and Monterey.

Anyone has any advice?